# SSRS linking parameters

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm very new to SSRS and SQL and I'm creating a report in Report Builder 3.0.

I have no problem in creating a new blank report, adding a datasource and a dataset. My Dataset is pretty basic:

```
SELECT  Employee_NO, Employee_Name
FROM    Employees
```

I have added a parameter for Employee_Name so the user can select an employee. I have also created a hidden parameter for Employee_NO

I have added two boxes on the report: One for Employee_Name and one for Employee_No. The first box is populated with the selection from the Employee_Name parameter but I somehow need to populate the other box with the specified users Employee_No. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way it usually works is you add a dataset with the query you need to populate the parameters (called dataset2 in this case):

```
select Employee_NO, Employee_Name from Employees
```

and then you create the parameter (right click on the parameters item on the report data tab) based on the dataset2

[image]

There you have your parameter.

To use it  on your main query you referenci it with a @:

```
select * from your_table 
where empid=@empId
```

just reference it:
[image]

Comment: And to complement this answer: Then on your textbox you just need to use the following expressions
=ReportParameters!ReportParameter1.Value (for the value)
=ReportParameters!ReportParameter1.Label (for the label)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time explaining this. Much appreciated!